# Como colocar mais dependências do spring boot pelo intelliJ?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, organização-de-projeto, dependências

eu estou seguindo [esse curso](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGbXsl9tzVg) de Spring boot que é dividido em algumas aulas. Na primeira aula ele baixou apenas algumas dependências e eu comecei meu projeto apenas com elas. Que são:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Porém na segunda aula do curso ele reiniciou o projeto e importou outras dependências, como faço para importar essas outras dependências por meio do IntelliJ assim como fiz no início do projeto sem reiniciá-lo? e por meio do IntelliJ, sem códigos. Se não for possível, eu já tentei colocar por meio de códigos e também não consegui, as dependências são:

1. H2 Database
2. Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 1):

Quando se está usando Maven as dependências podem ser encontradas no site MvnRepository. 
 No caso do H2 o link da última versão disponível é
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2/1.4.200 
E para o Spring JPA
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.5.5 
 Nessas páginas você vai achar uma janelinha onde tem as tags `<dependency> </dependency>`, é só copiá-las e colar no seu pom.xml